# disable ion-slide at startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to disable slide feature on startup and at the same time I still able to set my own active-page?

I found this does the trick, in HTML

```
<ion-slide-box active-page="disableSlide()">
    <ion-slide>Slide 1</ion-slide>
    <ion-slide ng-click="previous()">Slide 2</ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>Slide 3</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

In JavaScript,

```
$scope.disableSlide = function(){
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
    return 1;
}

$scope.previous = function(){
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
}
```

But when I click previous, I get this error

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'disableSlide()' used with directive 'ionSlideBox' is non-assignable!
```

The Demo here, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bodqor

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Check your html  `<body ng-controller="IntroCtrl"></ion-view>`

Comment: fixed, thanks, but the problem remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ion-slide-box>` doesn't have an `active-page` attribute as you can see in the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/).

You're getting that error cause you've disabled the slider:

```
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
```

but you still want to change slides with `ng-click`.

If you want to disable the slider when the view is shown you can use `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);` but you'd better wrap it in a function:

```
function changeSlideStatus()
{
    $scope.slideEnabled = !$scope.slideEnabled;
    $scope.slideStatusTest = $scope.slideEnabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled";

    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide($scope.slideEnabled); 
}
```

> `$scope.slideEnabled` is a boolean property which defines the status
>   of the slider.

When the navigation enters in your view you can change status:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
    changeSlideStatus();
});
```

You can play with this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S83isu?p=preview). In the header you can disable/enable the slider simply calling `changeSlideStatus();`:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">

  <button class="button button-positive"
          ng-click="changeStatus()">
    {{slideStatusTest}}
  </button>

</ion-nav-buttons>
```

> PS: It starts disabled.